# Search using voice command

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I got this simple problem whenever I say "search music click" its searching for 'search music click' too it's supposed to search my music file name click. I tried to put different variables but only boolean is the one that not causing an error.

```
if(voice_result.indexOf("search music") != -1){
voice_result.contains(voice_result)
String a = voice_result;
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_MEDIA_FOCUS, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ENTRY_CONTENT_TYPE);
intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, a);
startActivity(intent);}
```

the voice_result here is the process result of my voice and if ever I try to search a music from voice command it always search "search music risky" instead of "risky".

Answer (score 0):

You should write a parser/filter for whatever returned from the voice recognition api first. For example, you say "search music risk":

- Remove unnecessary or confusing strings like "search" "music" from the raw data. I suggest you use regex matcher and map the with a set of commands with values.
- After filtering the raw data (now only has "risk"), use the result for next job

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it gladly worked I put the replaceAll value to spaces and then trimmed it